# Ruby Convert String to Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm storing configuration data in hashes written in flat files. I want to import the hashes into my Class so that I can invoke corresponding methods.

example.rb

```
{ 
  :test1 => { :url => 'http://www.google.com' }, 
  :test2 => {
    { :title => 'This' } => {:failure => 'sendemal'}
  }
}
```

simpleclass.rb

```
class Simple
  def initialize(file_name)
    # Parse the hash
    file = File.open(file_name, "r")
    @data = file.read
    file.close
  end

  def print
    @data
  end

a = Simple.new("simpleexample.rb")
b = a.print
puts b.class   # => String
```

How do I convert any "Hashified" String into an actual Hash?

Comment: I would store it as JSON, read the file and use `JSON.parse`

Comment: use YML (yaml) or JSON to store hash in file and read it in ruby file as its actual data structure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `eval(@data)`, but really it would be better to use a safer and simpler data format like JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You can try **YAML.load** method

Example:

```
 YAML.load("{test: 't_value'}")
```

This will return following hash.

```
 {"test"=>"t_value"}
```

You can also use **eval** method

Example:

```
 eval("{test: 't_value'}")
```

This will also return same hash

```
  {"test"=>"t_value"}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

I would to this using the json gem.

In your Gemfile you use

```
gem 'json'
```

and then run `bundle install`.

In your program you require the gem.

```
require 'json'
```

And then you may create your "Hashfield" string by doing:

```
hash_as_string = hash_object.to_json
```

and write this to your flat file.

Finally, you may read it easily by doing:

```
my_hash = JSON.load(File.read('your_flat_file_name'))
```

This is simple and very easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be clear, it is only the hash that must be contained in a JSON file. Suppose that file is "simpleexample.json":

```
puts File.read("simpleexample.json")
  # #{"test1":{"url":"http://www.google.com"},"test2":{"{:title=>\"This\"}":{"failure":"sendemal"}}}
```

The code can be in a normal Ruby source file, "simpleclass.rb":

```
puts File.read("simpleclass.rb")
  # class Simple
  #   def initialize(example_file_name)
  #     @data = JSON.parse(File.read(example_file_name))
  #   end
  #   def print
  #     @data
  #   end
  # end
```

Then we can write:

```
require 'json'
require_relative "simpleclass"

a = Simple.new("simpleexample.json")
  #=> #<Simple:0x007ffd2189bab8 @data={"test1"=>{"url"=>"http://www.google.com"},
  #     "test2"=>{"{:title=>\"This\"}"=>{"failure"=>"sendemal"}}}> 
a.print
  #=> {"test1"=>{"url"=>"http://www.google.com"},
  #    "test2"=>{"{:title=>\"This\"}"=>{"failure"=>"sendemal"}}} 
a.class
  #=> Simple
```

To construct the JSON file from the hash:

```
h = { :test1=>{ :url=>'http://www.google.com' },
      :test2=>{ { :title=>'This' }=>{:failure=>'sendemal' } } }
```

we write:

```
File.write("simpleexample.json", JSON.generate(h))
  #=> 95
```